# Run command in Terminal from Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that needs to run a command in the terminal.
or i want to run this command in my app.

ssh -N -p 24 -g -D 1080 username@server

plz help me . tnx

Comment: is this true?
system("ssh -N -p 24 -g -D 1080 username@server")

Comment: yes that is true Naeim, it should work

Answer (score 4):

You've marked this question as `iphone` and `iphone-sdk`, but it's not possible to `fork` or `exec` in an App Store application.  If you need SSH connectivity for your application, you can use a library like [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/), but you won't be able to reuse the standard `ssh` command.

Answer (score 3):

Try ssh keys. Check out [ssh-keygen](http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html) for more information. Simply generate a key for yourself, put the public key (usually ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) in a file called ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the box you want to ssh into, and voila, it should just work :)

Comment: Just noticed that you're doing this in relation to an iPhone app (at least from the tags you've posted); I'm not certain this will work if you're trying to ssh from an iPhone to a server. You might want to explore alternatives to getting your information to the phone, perhaps by getting your app to query the server for information rather than getting the client to root around on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is the solution to your question ;)

Comment: tnx.
but this command will ask for password . then how to enter password? 
any solution ?

Comment: Set up ssh keys so that you don't need a password ?